# How can I access commandline from java code in android studio?

Tags: java, python, android, android-studio

Let me explain my problem, I have a python script of Linear Regression, It will get inputs from command line and will give output too!
I want to do this with my android app. so is there any way to give input from the app and get its output too?
if there is any other way to accomplish this task without using command line, then please tell me.

Comment: "if there is any other way to accomplish this task without using command line, then please tell me" -- you could write linear regression code in Java or Kotlin. Android does not have a Python interpreter.

Comment: @CommonsWare bro I tried writing using java and guess what, I was getting terrible results. I also want accuracy.

Comment: "I was getting terrible results" -- Java and Kotlin are perfectly capable languages for linear regression. A quick search in your favorite search engine for `java "linear regression"` will turn up various examples, such as [this one](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/97data/LinearRegression.java.html). [Apache Commons-Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math) has curve fitting code, though I have not tried that library on Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you cannot run python code in java. You should rewrite these codes in java.

Secondly, in android apps, you can not use command line.
Yes, it works with Java but an android application is not a command line application, it works different and it can't access to a console or a command line.

1. You should create a textbox and a button in GUI with XML in Android Studio.
2. Then you should create a onClickListener for this button.
3. At the end you should take params from this textbox and use them in onClickListener function with your codes.